# How to call a builtin function (or method) from C code of a Python extension module?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-itertools, extension-modules

What I currently want to accomplish is to tweak Pythons `itertools` module  function `combinations` to sort the passed `iterable` before creating combinations out of it with the goal of having the returned combinations sorted.

I am working on a Python extension module for the first time and my only experience up to now was to write and compile a "Hello World" like Python extension module, but I hope that my overall programming experience in a couple of programming languages is a solid enough foundation I can build upon to succeed on this challenge.

I know that there is a builtin Python function `sorted()` which can sort the iterable passed to `combinations` but I don't know how to call it from within the C code of the extension module.

I have tried just to write `iterable = sorted(iterable);` but even if the module compiles (with a warning) the import of the compiled module fails with `ImportError: cgitertools.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sorted`

My question is:

> **How to call the Pythons builtin method (using as example `sorted()`) from within C code of a Python extension module?**

Below all the details of what I have tried and why it didn't work:

```
combinations_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    combinationsobject *co;
    Py_ssize_t n;
    Py_ssize_t r;
    PyObject *pool = NULL;
    PyObject *iterable = NULL;
    Py_ssize_t *indices = NULL;
    Py_ssize_t i;
    static char *kwargs[] = {"iterable", "r", NULL};

    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "On:combinations", kwargs,
                                     &iterable, &r))
        return NULL;

    // iterable.sort(); doesn't work ... cgitertoolsmodule.c:2398:13: error: request for member ‘sort’ in something not a structure or union
    // iterable.__sort__(); doesn't work either with same error
    // COMPILES, but gives ERROR on import in Python: 
    iterable = sorted(iterable);

$ python3.6 cgitertoolsmodule-setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
building 'cgitertools' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c cgitertoolsmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/cgitertoolsmodule.o
cgitertoolsmodule.c: In function ‘combinations_new’:
cgitertoolsmodule.c:2400:16: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sorted’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     iterable = sorted(iterable);
                ^
cgitertoolsmodule.c:2400:14: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     iterable = sorted(iterable);
              ^
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/cgitertoolsmodule.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cgitertools.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

$ python3.6
Python 3.6.1 (default, Apr 18 2017, 23:00:41) 
[GCC 5.4.1 20160904] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from cgitertools import combinations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cgitertools.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sorted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the **sorted** function out of the builtins and than call it:

```
PyObject *builtins = PyEval_GetBuiltins(); 
PyObject *sorted = PyDict_GetItemString(builtins , "sorted");
PyObject *sorted_list = PyEval_CallFunction(sorted, "(O)", iterable);

//... do something with the sorted_list

Py_DECREF(sorted_list);
```

Comment: May you explain what is the "(0)" for?

Comment: Its the argument format for the Function, in this case - one positional argument that is an PyObject